# "Network error: Connection refused" in Putty when I'm trying to connect to my remote home Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, wireless, server, ssh, network-manager

I just set up a linux home server using http://linuxhomeserverguide.com/. I can connect to it from my desktop PC at home via putty using a local ip like 192.168.1.2 (just an example ip), but I want to connect to it via my public ip so I can connect to it from my work office. When I try to establish a connection to the public ip with port 22, i get that error "Network error: Connection refused". Did I set it up wrong? I forwarded port 80 to the server and can ping the ip address so it's not a network connection issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to forward the port 22 to your home server. Port 80 is the standard port of an webserver like Apache. 
You can ping your public IP without to forward any port.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I have not found this solution anywhere but here. Thanks this works.

Comment: I have another problem and I was wondering if you knew the answer to this as well: When I try to login with my username to my home server via winSCP I get an error Permission Denied when I try to edit a file in it. But I'm the owner of the pc and the server why am I being denied permission? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to edit files you need sudo